# Kinect RGB Camera getting cropped Image instead of full image by using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

I'm trying to extract RGB and Depth images from Microsoft Kinect V1, I'm also using OpenCV 3.4 display the image from the Kinect. This is the following code, I'm using libfreenect driver for Ubuntu and OpenCV:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <libfreenect/libfreenect.hpp>
#include <pthread.h>
#define CV_NO_BACKWARD_COMPATIBILITY
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#define FREENECTOPENCV_WINDOW_D "Depthimage"
#define FREENECTOPENCV_WINDOW_N "Normalimage"
#define FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_DEPTH 3
#define FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_DEPTH 1
#define FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_WIDTH 640
#define FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_HEIGHT 480
#define FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_WIDTH 640
#define FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_HEIGHT 480

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat depthimg, rgbimg, tempimg, canny_temp, canny_img;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_depth = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_rgb = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t cv_thread;

// callback for depthimage, called by libfreenect
void depth_cb(freenect_device *dev, void *depth, uint32_t timestamp)

{
    Mat depth8;
    Mat mydepth = Mat( FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_WIDTH,FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_HEIGHT, CV_16UC1, depth);

    mydepth.convertTo(depth8, CV_8UC1, 1.0/4.0);
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_depth );
    memcpy(depthimg.data, depth8.data, 640*480);
    // unlock mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_depth );

}

// callback for rgbimage, called by libfreenect

void rgb_cb(freenect_device *dev, void *rgb, uint32_t timestamp)
{

    // lock mutex for opencv rgb image
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_rgb );
    memcpy(rgbimg.data, rgb, 640*480);
    // unlock mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_rgb );
}

/*
 * thread for displaying the opencv content
 */
void *cv_threadfunc (void *ptr) {
    depthimg = Mat(FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_HEIGHT, FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_WIDTH, CV_8UC1);
    rgbimg = Mat(FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_HEIGHT, FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);
    tempimg = Mat(FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_HEIGHT, FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);
    canny_img = Mat(FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_HEIGHT, FREENECTOPENCV_RGB_WIDTH, CV_8UC1);
    canny_temp = Mat(FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_HEIGHT, FREENECTOPENCV_DEPTH_WIDTH, CV_8UC3);

    // use image polling
    while (1)
    {
        //lock mutex for depth image
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_depth );

        imshow(FREENECTOPENCV_WINDOW_D,depthimg);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_depth );

        //lock mutex for rgb image
        pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex_rgb );

        cvtColor(rgbimg,tempimg,CV_BGR2RGB);
        cvtColor(tempimg, canny_img, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        imshow(FREENECTOPENCV_WINDOW_N, rgbimg);

        //unlock mutex
        pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex_rgb );

        // wait for quit key
        if(cvWaitKey(15) == 27)
            break;

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return NULL;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    freenect_context *f_ctx;
    freenect_device *f_dev;

    int res = 0;
    int die = 0;
    printf("Kinect camera test\n");

    if (freenect_init(&f_ctx, NULL) < 0)
    {
        printf("freenect_init() failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (freenect_open_device(f_ctx, &f_dev, 0) < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not open device\n");
        return 1;
    }

    freenect_set_depth_callback(f_dev, depth_cb);
    freenect_set_video_callback(f_dev, rgb_cb);
    //freenect_set_video_format(f_dev, FREENECT_VIDEO_RGB);

    // create opencv display thread
    res = pthread_create(&cv_thread, NULL, cv_threadfunc, NULL);
    if (res)
    {
        printf("pthread_create failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("init done\n");

    freenect_start_depth(f_dev);
    freenect_start_video(f_dev);

    while(!die && freenect_process_events(f_ctx) >= 0 );
}
```

This is the result from the Kinect:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kx5b.png)

Why is the output from RGB camera cropped in half? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do u get the same result without using threads?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen similar behavior while working on mobile apps with OpenCV and trying to display results. I can't entirely nail what the problem is, but it seems a "corrupted" version of the image is shown when you pre-allocate memory for a matrix (from a previous operation) that you iteratively re-use within a code block.

For example, you prepare a mat to store a constant stream of video frames and constantly re-use it in a loop. I'm not sure if this is your exact case. Can you write your image to disk and see if this result is also "cropped"?